# Interpretation of subjects of gerunds

Tags: pronouns, gerunds

A paper on the implicit subjects of gerunds that I'm currently reading says that the sentences (1a) and (2a) sound off because *John*, though semantically appropriate, cannot be the antecedent for the gerunds in bold. If you agree with these judgements, would you say that (1b) and (2b) represent an improvement over (1a) and (2a), taking the first-person pronouns as the agent subjects of the gerunds?

> (1a) **Having shaved** already shows that Mary arrived more than 5 minutes after **John** did
>
> (1b) **Having shaved** already shows that Mary arrived more than 5 minutes after **we** did
>
> (2a) **Missing so many training sessions** only shows that the commander should have fired **John** sooner
>
> (2b) **Missing so many training sessions** only shows that the commander should have fired **us** sooner

On a related note, the paper says (3b) is also crashingly bad, especially when compared to (3a) which is clearly intelligible. Would you say that (3c) is an improvement over (3b)? Note that I'm not requiring it to have the meaning that the latter would have if it weren't ungrammatical--I'm just asking whether (3c) is an intelligible English sentence under any interpretation.

> (3a) Mary knew that John thought that killing himself would show that leaving him had been a mistake
>
> (3b) Mary knew that John thought that killing herself would show that leaving her had been a mistake
>
> (3c) Mary knew that John thought that killing herself would show that leaving her was a mistake

Comment: 1b doesn't make sense to me because it's not clear _who_ had shaved! I would change 1a to _John's having shaved already shows that Mary [must have] arrived more than five minutes after he did_. Did you intend to change _himself_ to _herself_ in sentence 3?

Comment: The latter examples sound off if for no other reason than that they're convoluted. Gricean maxims are as important as grammaticality.

Comment: When juggling potential contexts like this, it's well to remember that one good definition of grammaticality is that it measures the ease with which a context for interpreting the sentence can be found. If you can't think of a situation where someone might say it, it's ungrammatical for you.